# Java Looping Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, shift

How do I make this loop properly? it right now So it loops but it does not  loop properly. It does this
Here are the numbers:

```
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 [1]
```

How many positions do you want to shift?: 2

```
2 1 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 [3]
```

How many positions do you want to shift?: 4

the [] are where its suppose to ask me for my input instead of me just putting in a input
its suppose to run like this:

re are the numbers:

```
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

How many positions do you want to shift?: 1

```
2 1 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3
```

How many positions do you want to shift?: 4

```
System.out.println("Here are the numbers:");
for (i=0; i<numberArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(numberArray[i] + " ");
}

while (x != input.nextInt()){

    System.out.printf("How many positions do you want to shift?: ");
    int shiftTimes=input.nextInt();
    for( i = 0; i < shiftTimes; ++i) 

        shift.Shifter(numberArray);

        for(j = 0; j < numberArray.length; j++)
            System.out.printf(numberArray[j]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Also How Do I make it exit the program when I enter in a invalid number and how do I get get it to read a negative value and get it to shift left

Edit: heres my shifter code

```
public static void Shifter(int[] list)
{
int i;  

if (list.length < 2) return;

int last = list[list.length - 1];

for(i = list.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
list[i] = list[i - 1];
}
list[0] = last;
}
```

Comment: This sort of looks like a BF compiler your trying to build.

Comment: Did you write the Shifter method?

Comment: @BinaryJudy Yes I did. I blanked out and forgot to add it

Answer (score 1):

This should work for right shift. It should work with inputs larger then array length as well.

```
for (int i = shiftTimes%numberArray.length; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(numberArray[numberArray.length - i] + " ");
}
for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.length - shiftTimes%numberArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(numberArray[i] + " ");
}
```

Reversing this logic should produce a left shift approach.

An invalid input would be the length of the array (because the result will be the same) or 0 because that doesn't do anything:

```
if (shiftTimes == numberArray.length || shiftTimes == 0) {
    // present error to user
}
```

UPDATE: Putting the logic in your function. Also updated the invalid input check.

```
public static void Shifter(int[] list, int input)
{
    for (int i = input%list.length; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(list[list.length - i] + " ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length - input%list.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

The function call would be:

```
Shifter(numberArray, shiftTimes);
```

Comment: Thank you for you help :) if you wouldnt mind could you add a loop code because I've been trying but I just can't seem to get it. it is suppose to Loop until I input the a string